# Deprecation error in audio_service plugin flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, deprecated, background-service, audio-service

I tried to run an application but it is giving the following deprecation error. I have upgraded to flutter 3 since then I am getting this error. I have tried flutter clean, pub get, pub repair.
Still, the error is constant.
I am using  audio_service: ^0.18.2 and  just_audio: ^0.9.24 versions.
[image: This is an snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

That error means you are compiling against the next beta release of Android which deprecates some methods that were being used by audio_service. Someone has already submitted an issue on the project's GitHub page to support this beta version of Android, and the latest audio_service release should now support it.